# Convert Raw URI to displayable image C#

Tags: windows, winforms, .net-4.8

### The Issue

I am using A TOTP Library That Returns URI Data For The Scannable QR Code And I Need Help To Get The Code Either To Display In Web Browser Object In Windows Forms Or As An Image.

This Is The Data That I Get: [The Gist Containing The Data](https://gist.github.com/DDX5/6e062b24e80c8b2c76567e2f007eeaf0)

### The Expected Outcome

Either The QR Code Displayed In A C# .Net Framework Windows Forms WebBrowser Component
Or The QR Code As A BMP Or PNG File

### What I Have Tried

I Have Tried To Download The QR By Using WebClient And WebClient.openRead(URI);

To Which I Got The Following Error: [The Error](https://gist.github.com/DDX5/fb58bf31ff061187eb42dbb273a10a41)

I Have Also Tried To Use The WebBrowser Component By Passing In The URI And Then Refreshing, Show.

To Which There Was No Display, Or It Failed To Webpage

---

I am At A Loss Here As I Have Googled For An Answer But Returned Blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following Is For Converting To Image File Only And Not Displaying In
WebBrowser. This Has Been Tested And Is Working Correctly.

Inside The First Gist Link Is A Data Scheme URL/URI All You Need To Do Is The Following.

1. Convert The URL/URI Into A String.
2. Split The String With The Char Delimiter Of ','.
3. Retrieve The String At Index 1 and not 0.
4. Convert The String Using Convert.fromBase64String Passing In The String Containing The String At Index 1
5. Create A Temporary With The .png Extension.
6. Write The Byte Array Into The File.

And That Will Save The Image Into A File For Easy Retrieval Using Image.FromFile.

```
 Uri Data = new Uri(Setup.QrCodeImage); //This Is Located From A TOPT Generator
 string[] Objects = Data.ToString().Split(',');
 string Base64String = Objects[1];
 byte[] ImageD = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);
 string P = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".png";
 File.WriteAllBytes(P, ImageD);
 Image image = Image.FromFile(P);
```

If You Found This Helpful I'm Glad.

Comment: You can replace all that comes after `byte[] ImageD ...` to `Image image = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(ImageD);` (i.e., no need to save to file). -- You can also show that Image in a WebBrower, setting that string as the `src` URL of an `<IMG>` element.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for that. I had no idea about the imageconverter class. This will definitely help save time and space